# How to copy the text along with font styling in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, styling

What I am doing is simple. I am simply copy and paste the font from flutter It copies only the letters the font styles are not copying.

Answer (score 0):

styling properties are given to display text in given Style it is not the property of text. Text is copied in UTF byte Format so, When you copy text Only text gets copied the style and Other property does not get copied.

Flutter works with custom fonts and you can apply a custom font across an entire app or to individual widgets. This recipe creates an app that uses custom fonts with the following steps:

Import the font files.
Declare the font in the pubspec.
Set a font as the default.
Use a font in a specific widget.